# Compiling transformation error after install EF power tools on VS Community 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I´m trying to generate View Entity Data Model (Read-only) using Entity Framework Power Tool on Visual Studio Community 2017, but I´m getting the following errors:

> 1. Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'EfTextTemplateHost' could not be found (are you missing a using
>      directive or an assembly
>      reference?)   NinjaDomain.DataModel   C:\Users\Documents\visual studio
>      2017\Projects\NinjaDomain.Module2Demo\NinjaDomain.DataModel\CodeTemplates\ReverseEngineerCodeFirst\Mapping.tt
> 2. Compiling transformation: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '?' because '?' does not contain a public definition
>      for 'GetEnumerator'   NinjaDomain.DataModel   C:\Users\Documents\visual
>      studio
>      2017\Projects\NinjaDomain.Module2Demo\NinjaDomain.DataModel\CodeTemplates\ReverseEngineerCodeFirst\Mapping.tt

Anyone has an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you manage to found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2017 I recommend to use [**EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator) instead. It's already supported in Visual Studio 2017 and it does the same you're trying to achieve, so you can re-generate your entity model every time you need it executing **Run Custom Tools** option from the context menu on your `.tt` template file. EF Power Tools hasn't been updated for new VS versions since 2013.

Comment: It new extension generates others errrors: Loading the include file 'EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude' returned a null or empty string. The transformation will not be run.
Failed to resolve include text for file:C:\Users\NinjaDomain.Module2Demo\NinjaDomain.DataModel\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude NinjaDomain.DataModel C:\Users\Projects\NinjaDomain.Module2Demo\NinjaDomain.DataModel\NinjaContext.edmx

Comment: Oh, but you're trying to generate your model from .edmx file?  EF Reverse POCO generator allows you to generate your model directly from your DB, not from an edmx.

Comment: I was reading about that error, and it's like you need to install this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762, but that is for VS 2012 and VS2013 (more info https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator), but I think you should try to generate your model directly  from your DB specifying the connection string in your tt file. That is how I'm using it in my VS 2017 projects

Comment: Ah! No, I'm trying to generate the model from a class